# The method for searching in the Spring controller does not work

Tags: java, html, jpa, model-view-controller

Please help solve the problem with the search

The method for searching in the Spring controller does not work

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No property user found for type User!
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property user found for type User!

When I try to search for users by username, I get an error referring to a line in UserService:

> return userRepo.findByUsername (search, pageable);

UserRepo:

```
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
User findByUsername(String username);

User findByActivationCode(String code);

Page<UserDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);

Page<UserDto> findByUsername(@Param("username") String search, Pageable pageable);
```

}

UserServise:

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
@Autowired
private UserRepo userRepo;

public Page<UserDto> userList(Pageable pageable, String search) {
    if (search != null && !search.isEmpty()) {
        return userRepo.findByUsername(search, pageable);
    } else {
        return userRepo.findAll(pageable);
    }
}
```

Dto:

```
public class UserDto {
    private Long id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    ...

    public UserDto(User user) {
        this.id = user.getId();
        this.firstname = user.getFirstname();
        this.lastname = user.getLastname();
        this.username = user.getUsername();
        this.email = user.getEmail();
        ...
    }... + getters
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/users")
public String readAllUsers(
        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "") String search,
        @PageableDefault(sort = {"id"}, direction = Sort.Direction.DESC) Pageable pageable,
        Model model) {
    Page<UserDto> page = userService.userList(pageable, search);
    model.addAttribute("url", "/admin/users");
    model.addAttribute("page", page);
    model.addAttribute("search", search);
    model.addAttribute("roles", Role.values());
    return "adminUsers";
}
```

Form:

```
<form action="/admin/users" method="get" class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <!-- Default input -->
            <input type="search" name="search" value="${search?ifExists}"
                   placeholder="Enter you query" aria-label="Search" class="form-control">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm my-0 p" type="submit">
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </button>

        </form>
```

Full text Error: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cA0Gs1CKECHMZkgzlMqeHbK5WZLatowk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Your repository is working with `User`, it cannot return `Page<UserDto>`... only `Page<User>`. You will need to map `User` to `UserDto` after it is returned by repository.

Comment: Can you write a little more in detail? I’m just learning Spring, I don’t quite understand.

Comment: It is necessary to transfer to the page exactly Dto with it it is impossible (

Comment: change the return type to `Page<User>`.

Comment: And how to do to return Dto?

Comment: You can [map it](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper#how-do-i-get-started).

Comment: Because findAll works well with UserDto, and findByUsername does not want ((

Comment: Without the use of libraries, is it easier to not change in any way?

Answer (score 0):

instead of this: Page , replace with Page.